functions with get_post_meta
I'm working on a function for bibliographic citations with get_post_meta.
A bibliographic citation contains several elements, (author, date, title, etc.), each of these elements is a get_post_meta value. The bibliographic citation function orders these elements according to bibliographic standards (e.g. APA).
Example
Function for elements the citation
function editorial() {
    global $wp_query;
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    $editorial = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'acervo_editorial', true);
    if (!empty($editorial)) {
        echo $editorial.', ';
    }
}

function pubdate() {
    global $wp_query;
    $post = $wp_query->post;
    $pubdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'acervo_pubdate', true);
    if (!empty($pubdate )) {
        echo $pubdate.', ';
    }
}

function for citation
function article_citation() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $wp_query; 

    echo '<p>';
    editorial();
    pubdate();
    echo '</p>';
}

If I put the echo get_post_meta directly in the template it works
$pubdate = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'acervo_pubdate', true);
        if (!empty($pubdate )) {
            echo $pubdate.', ';
}

but if I put the citation function some elements work and others don't. Something is wrong but I don't know what it is.
article_citation();


Why are you segmenting it all separately?  Try adding $post to the functions, like so:  function editorial( $post )
I also don't think this is necessary in your article_citation function;  global $wpdb; and global $wp_query;  Personally I'd just get the meta in the article_citation function unless it's because you want to use the other two separately in other areas.

Thank you. I'm going to try it
